# How i can access unique date

Tags: soql

how i can access unique day my Soql is

```
select Id, Date__c from Object__c where ORDER BY Date__c DESC
```

this Soql is giving me data as

```
2013-08-17 04:59:06
2013-08-13 04:59:06
2013-08-13 04:59:06
2013-08-12 04:59:06
2013-08-10 04:59:06
2013-08-10 04:59:06
```

But i want only day wise i.e

```
2013-08-17 04:59:06
2013-08-13 04:59:06
2013-08-12 04:59:06
2013-08-10 04:59:06
```

How i can do this.

Comment: You don't care about the objects themselves, just the unique dates for which there is at least one occurrence in the database?

Comment: Ya just unique date..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an aggregate query like this:

```
select day_only(createdDate)
from account
group by day_only(createdDate)
order by day_only(createdDate)
```

This returns one row for each date that has an account created on it. You can apply this to your own object and add whatever where conditions are relevant. Note that the result will be a list of AggregateResult and not a list of account or object__c.

Refer also to http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm